# dotnet restore not working from inside a dockerfile

Tags: c#, .net, docker, nuget

I am trying to run `RUN dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config Ithought.Web.sln` from a dockefile which looks like:-

```
FROM www.image.from:5000/a/private.docker-registry:1 AS build
WORKDIR /delivery

# Copy csproj and sln and restore as distinct layers
COPY NuGet.config .
COPY Ithought.Web/Ithought.Web.csproj Ithought.Web/
COPY Ithought.Web.Delivery/Ithought.Web.Delivery.csproj Ithought.Web.Delivery/
COPY Ithought.Web.sln .
RUN dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config Ithought.Web.sln     //it fails here
```

but docker build fails with the following error:-

```
ERROR [build  7/10] RUN dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config Ithought.Web.sln                              1.5s
------
 > [build  7/10] RUN dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config Ithought.Web.sln:
#14 1.190 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.207/NuGet.targets(246,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/Smidge/src/Smidge/Smidge.csproj" was not found. [/delivery/Ithought.Web.sln]
```

However when I try `dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config Ithought.Web.sln` from outside of the dockerfile it works fine

Please note that along with the public nuget feed I am also trying to restore packages from a private nuget feed and I am wondering if docker is able to authenticate with the private nuget although I have the private nuget's credentials added to the nuget.config file. I have seen a lot of similar questions on the internet but I have not come across anyone who is trying to do a `dotnet restore` from within a `dockerfile` from a private nuget

Comment: Looks like you have a reference to Smidge.csproj from your solution file.

Comment: Yes, `Smidge.csproj` is present at the correct location and I am able to run `dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config Ithought.Web.sln` from outside of dockerfile because of which I think `Smidge.csproj` is not the problem

Comment: But if you don't copy smidge.csproj into the docker container, then it'll complain that it can't find it.